# Energy-frequency dependency of a photon and its medium of propagation

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, frequency

Is the equation relating a photon's energy to its frequency the same regardless of its medium of propagation? And for the equation relating its momentum to wavelength as well?

Comment: @DavidZ I completely miss the point why you delete my answer.

Comment: @DavidZ I would flag you for this but I am powerless against your 64k reputation. You win, science loses.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty. As a reply to my incorrectly moderated answer you say that the Minkowski Abraham controversy "sounds remarkably classical". This statement is entirely subjective. Can you provide references or information to support your musing?

Answer (score 0):

The energy of a photon is the same: $E=hf$. Frequency of a photon does not change with medium. It is only the speed and the wavelength that is different.

Comment: It is not as easy as you write. There has been a very long controversy over the energy of a photon in a medium.

Comment: Would it be possible for the energy to stay the same while the momentum differs?

Comment: I think you made a mistake. Try to add quote from renowned resources. Is it possible to reason that way? If frequency is deemed constant, what "are we left with" may not clear things up. As indeed, if speed changes (velocity equals frequency time wavelength)  one and the same colour changes it's wavelenght. Logicwise, that is not excluded. So it's about acknowledging that "light" ("rest mass zero") must always travel by c. That's a law.

Comment: True, thanks for pointing it out.  I have deleted my previous comment.